# CSS to place text content of Bootstrap Tab Control (horizontal tabs) under the tab - preclude text wrapping around tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following html code contains a Bootstrap Tab Control.  In my sample I have a few nested Bootstrap Tab Controls.  The first (left most) Tab contains a nested Tab Control with 3 horizontal tabs.  The 2nd tab contains a nested Tab control with 3 vertically aligned tabs.  The 3rd and 4th tabs just contain plain text content.  The issue that I'm having is that for the horizontal tabs (nested and not nested) the text content displays at the same level as the tabs (the horizontally aligned tabs) - the text is wrapping around the tabs.  I want to display the content of the horizontally aligned tabs "Underneath" the respective tab(s) not wrapping around the tabs.  What is the CSS to accomplish this?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

    .tab-content > .tab-pane,
    .pill-content > .pill-pane {
      display: none;
    }

    .tab-content > .active,
    .pill-content > .active {
      display: block;
    }                

     .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li {
      float: none;
    }

    .tabbable > .nav-tabs > li > a {
      min-width: 74px;
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .tabbable > .nav-tabs {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 19px;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .tabbable > .nav-tabs > li > a {
      margin-right: -1px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
         -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
              border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;

    }

    .tabbable  > .nav-tabs .active > a,
    .tabbable  > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
    .tabbable  > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {                                
      border-color: red blue red red;
      *border-right-color: lime;
      background-color: lime;
    }

    .tabbable > .nav > li > a:hover {
       background-color: red;
    }

    .tabbable > .nav > li > a {
       background-color: orange;
    }

    .tab-content {
        color: red;
        }




  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Tabs</h3>

            <div class="tabbable">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab"><b>OneA abcdefg</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab"><b>TwoA</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#twee" data-toggle="tab"><b>ThreeA</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#fourth" data-toggle="tab"><b>fourthA</b></a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">


                            <div class="tabbable tabs-top">
                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li><a href="#oneb" data-toggle="tab"><b>OneB</b></a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#twob" data-toggle="tab"><b>TwoB</b></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tweeb" data-toggle="tab"><b>ThreeB</b></a></li>
                              </ul>
                              <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="oneb">First Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="twob">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
                                Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tweeb">Third amuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
                               </div>
                            </div>



                    </div>

                  <!-- ------------------- -->

                <div class="tab-pane" id="two">

                      <div class="col-md-7">        
                          <!-- tabs left -->
                          <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                              <li><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><b>One</b></a></li>
                              <li class="active"><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><b>Two</b></a></li>
                              <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><b>Twee</b></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content">
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="a">A) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius </div>
                             <div class="tab-pane  active" id="b">B) Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet</div>
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="c">C) Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                      </div>

                </div>



                <div class="tab-pane" id="twee">Third amuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="fourth">fourth amuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae.</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabs -->
        </div>
     </div>
</form
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my desired result by adding a bunch of 
s (like 5) before the text of each div in the respective tab (inline 
s).  I think this is the hokey way to do it.  How can I achieve the same effect using CSS for each of these divs?

Comment: that was br tags -- I added br tags to place my content underneath the respective (horizontal) tab.